# Chrome Extensions and Translations

Tags: javascript, internationalization, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension in English and everything works fine.

Looking in to internationalisation, I read the following details:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html

I created the relevant JSON files and have checked their validity.

Now I am trying to allow support for my options page to support multiple langauges.
It is just static HTML.

From the link above, it says you can use the format

```
  __MSG_messagename__
```

in JSON and css files.

Can i use this in my HTML files too? It seems overkill to have to do something like:

```
function getMessage() {
  var message = chrome.i18n.getMessage("click_here", ["string1", "string2"]);
  document.getElementById("languageSpan").innerHTML = message;
}
```

for each string that needs translating!

My tests show that there is no option apart from setting the innerHTML which is annoying if the page has lots of translations to support

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently can't use the message format directly in HTML files: only in your manifest and in CSS files. There's a bug open for the feature request, however: you can star http://crbug.com/115800 to track progress.

That bug notes a workaround (sorta): you can have entirely separate HTML files for each language. That's a terrible workaround, I know, but it's there if that's interesting to you. :)

Comment: Thanks Mike. A bit annoying but thanks for the quick reponse!

Comment: Star the bug. :) The counts are certainly used by the teams when triaging bugs, so it's the simplest way of expressing interest in a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in framework for this but don't give up. I've created one that allows you to do exactly what you want;

https://gist.github.com/1977657#file_i18n.coffee

I use this in my [Template](https://github.com/neocotic/template) extension as it simplifies i18n in pages as well as your source code. Just call `i18n.init` once and it looks for all elements on that page with i18n attributes and modifies them accordingly, and it even supports string substitutions with little extra work.

#### Example:

```
<a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf" i18n-content="name" i18n-values=".style.direction:@@bidi_dir;title:description"></a>
<!-- Will be modified to something like this... -->
<a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf" i18n-content="name" i18n-values=".style.direction:@@bidi_dir;title:description" style="direction: ltr" title="Quickly and easily copies info on the current page using a simple and unique template system">Template</a>
```

For a better understanding I recommend looking at the code itself, but for more examples you should look at the [code](https://github.com/neocotic/template/blob/master/src/lib/options.coffee) and [HTML](https://github.com/neocotic/template/blob/master/src/pages/options.html) source for my options page.

I hope you find it useful.